# Passing an String Argument to a Report from a Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button which I want to use to change the `RowSource` of a MS Chart object on a report.
I am passing this string through a `DoCmd.OpenReport...` command. The string passess on fine and also splits well using the `Split()` function.
the secornd part of the string works well and shows as the caption of the label, but the first part of the string fails with error: 
`You entered and expression that has an invalid reference to the property RowSource`
My code is:

On form:

```
Private Sub filterPrint_Click()
Dim strArg As String

strArg = "SELECT [Category],Sum([SumOfNetPrice]) AS [SumOfSumOfNetPrice] FROM [qryChart] GROUP BY [Category]" & "|" & "Report by Category"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFinal", acViewPreview, OpenArgs:=strArg

End Sub
```

On report:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strArg As Variant

strArg = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")

Me.lbl_Heading = strArg(1)
    Me.reportChart.RowSource = strArg(0) 

If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    Me.OrderByOn = True

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the first part of the string execute as an actual query?

Comment: Can you not change the SQL of the underling chart query before opening the report?

Comment: If I Put `MsgBox(strArg(0))` I see the string `SELECT [Category],Sum([SumOfNetPrice]) AS [SumOfSumOfNetPrice] FROM [qryChart] GROUP BY [Category]`

Comment: @Applecore Isn't the Open even the highest in hierarchy?

Comment: AFAIK, cannot change report textboxes ControlSource once report begins rendering and same for chart RowSource. Why do you need to programmatically change chart RowSource? May or may not be an issue, but missing semi-colon at end of SQL.

Comment: @June7 are you saying that this may impossible? Do you have any suggestions on how to do it before rendering begins? By the way the semi-colon at the end makes no difference.

Comment: @Fil - i am asking if you create that create in design (sql mode) does it actually run?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes it does

Comment: Open report in design view, modify RowSource, save then open. VBA can manage this. Again, why are you programmatically changing RowSource?

Comment: @June7 There is a combobox on the main form and chart. The combobox changes the `RowSource` of the Chart which is expected to be displayed on the report. after the button click. I don't know any better on how to do this efficiently.

Comment: I still don't understand why. What exactly is changed in the chart RowSource?

Comment: If the chart's RowSource is a SQL statement, create a Query instead to use as the RowSource for the chart in the report, and then modify the Query's SQL (`CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySource").SQL="SELECT Category......`) **before** you open the report.

Comment: @June7 The chart's RowSource's query is the one that changes, This changes swiftly on a form's chart. But doesn't on reports.

Comment: As @Applecore says, change query object using QueryDefs. I still don't know what it is you are changing in the RowSource query. Why do you need to set RowSource to different query statement? What is different?

Comment: @Applecore could you please expand your method a bit further?

Comment: @June7, If you have a form bounded to query as it's record source, and you add a MS Chart object to the form, you can dynamically change the charts record Source by setting it to a SQL string variable using `Me.testChart.RecordSource = strstring`.  Works fine. I thought it would also do the same thing with a report if I were to add a Chart on the report and pass the Charts `RecordSource` string variable as an argument on the `DoCmd.OpenReport...` command. It would be nice if something like this was possible. Regarding using `QueryDefs()` I don't know where to start.

Comment: I know that can be done with charts on form. What I still don't know is why you need to PROGRAMMATICALLY set chart RowSource. I build many charts with an SQL statement as RowSource but never had to programmatically change the RowSource. As for using QueryDefs to modify a query object, do some research. Set chart RowSource to that query object then you modify the query object structure before running report.

Comment: @June7 Pardon me for luck of sleep. Thanks for your direction. I now get it. One question though, won't using `QueryDefs()` method be slower than building individual queries for individual reports? I suppose it would be about efficiency vs size.

Comment: I don't know if slower but doubt it would be noticeable to user.